# Use CSS to autosize width content

Tags: html, css, css-tables, col

I have a table with two columns.  The second column should ALWAYS show it's content perfectly and the width should be automatically calculated based on the content.  The first column should be as wide as possible up to a certain point (max width).  I am unfortunately only used to WPF not HTML.  In WPF I would write the following:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="600" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

My HTML is:

```
<colgroup>
   <col class="fullWidthCol" />
   <col class="autoWidthCol" />
</colgroup>
```

My CSS is:

```
.fullWidthCol {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 600px;
}

.autoWidthCol {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

I'm sure I'm not even close.  It's ignoring my max-width and sizing the first column as large as possible pushing the second column to the right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `td` doesn't accept the `max-width` specification.  Just use `width` instead; on a `td`, `width` will have the same effect.

Example:

```
table
{ width: 100%; }

.fullWidthCol
{ width: 300px; }

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="fullWidthCol">The first column should be as wide as possible up to a certain point (max width). </td>
    <td class="autoWidthCol">The second column should ALWAYS show it's content perfectly and the width should be automatically calculated based on the content. </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Or see http://jsfiddle.net/HdSA2/.

Comment: That does not work. The first column is 300px and the other grows forever. I can't specify '300px' because the content changes and is dynamic. It just needs to size to fit whatever is in it.  The other column cannot grow forever; it needs to stop at a certain point. Perhaps this is not possible?

Comment: I guess I'm confused.  You want to constrain the first column to be X pixels or smaller?  The JSfiddle does that.
How do you want the second column to be constrained? Do you need to constrain the entire width of the table?

Comment: The JSFiddle doesn't do that.  The second column in the JSFiddle grows forever.  I'm wanting the second column to grow as the table grows, but I want a max-width.  The first column is always 300px.  I want it exactly as big as it needs to be based on content.  Maybe this just isn't possible in CSS.

Comment: @Paul - Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/HdSA2/1/. There's a fixed width on col1, and col2 shrinks if it has less content. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry, no. Your 'max-width' on the table is not being used at all. Change it to 150px instead of 400px and you'll see the table does not shrink. You have: Col1 = Fixed Size, Col2 = Auto Sized (NOT constrained, but sized according to content.)  I want: One column auto sized (You've got this part), but the other column I want as LARGE as possible and not fixed.  BUT, I want the table to have a max-width.  So if the table is 800 pixels, then one column is auto sized, and the other column is (800px - Auto Sized Column px)